# EF : Joining an entity to itself

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities, Class and Condition. I need to create a relationship between them so that if a class meets a condition, the next class is suggested.

So I have :

```
ClassId(PrimaryKey) - ConditionId(PrimaryKey)
```

And in between them I want to add an entity something like this :

```
ClassId(PrimaryKey) -  ClassId(PrimaryKeyAndForeignKey) - ConditionId(PrimaryKey)
                       ConditionId(ForeignKey)
                       NextClassId(ForeignKey)
```

In this entity ClassId would be a foreign key to Class but since it can only have one Condition it is also a primary key of this table. And then ConditionId is a foreign key to Condition and NextClassId is another foreign key to Class.

Would this be a good way to do this? Would it be better to give the entity in the middle its own primary key rather than using ClassId as a primary key?

Comment: It appears to be a matter of personal preference, akin to an 'opinion-based' decision. Both models—FK Unique and PK-to-PK relationship—are endorsed. Feel free to choose the one that aligns better with your specific scenario. For more details, refer to the official documentation: [Entity Framework Core Relationships - One-to-One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one).